# git filter-repo --replace-text does nothing

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I am working on an old local repo which I created when I was less aware of security/git. I comitted files containing passwords. I have corrected this in the source code and updated .gitignore, now I want to purge the senstive strings from the git history. I do not want to affect the current files, or remove the history, just replace the strings with `***REMOVED***`

Based on other answers I have tried the following:

`git filter-repo --replace-text replace.txt`

using `replace.txt`

```
regex:\$password = ["'].*?["']==>$password = "***REMOVED***"
regex:\$servername = ["'].*?["']==>$servername = "***REMOVED***"
regex:\$username = ["'].*?["']==>$username = "***REMOVED***"
regex:\$dbname = ["'].*?["']==>$dbname = "***REMOVED***";
regex:\$host = ["'].*?["']==>$host = "***REMOVED***"
regex:\$db_name = ["'].*?["']==>$db_name = "***REMOVED***";
regex:\$smtp_server = ["'].*?["']==>$smtp_server = "***REMOVED***";
regex:\$smtp_user = ["'].*?["']==>$smtp_user = "***REMOVED***"
regex:\$smtp_pw = ["'].*?["']==>$smtp_pw = "***REMOVED***";
```

(I have also tried it with just the string literals in case it was a regex problem)

This gives an output of

```
Parsed 90 commits
New history written in 4.71 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
HEAD is now at xxx
Enumerating objects: 2299, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2299/2299), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (719/719), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2299/2299), done.
Total 2299 (delta 1579), reused 2283 (delta 1563), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 6.87 seconds.
```

But this doesn't change anything - I can still see the strings in the git history, and running
`git log -S <one of the passwords>` seems to confirm this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

### Answer - replace.txt must be UTF-8

The replace.txt was in UTF-16 encoding for some reason, changing to UTF-8 has fixed the issue